# R: replace regex in a data frame and reserving its structure

Tags: r, regex

say I have a data.frame 'df' and I want to run the following code:

```
df <- sub("^\\s+", "", (df))
```

Now df is a 'character' vector. 
How can I edit this code to preserve the data.frame structure?

Best Regards,

Comment: Have you tried `df <- data.frame(sub("^\\s+", "", df))` and `df <- as.data.frame(sub("^\\s+", "", df))`?

Comment: You need to apply it to the different *columns*  not to the `df` itself.

Comment: Thanks `dreamer`. Indeed converting back to a data.frame was the answer! Would you like to post it?

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` should work:

`df <- sapply(df, function(x) {sub("^\\s+", "", x)})`

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bugle, that would change the data.frame into a matrix. I had to do what `dreamer` suggested in his comment by using `as.data.frame`.